# How do I create a javascript app that sends data to matlab?

Tags: javascript, c++, reactjs, mongodb, matlab

I have a project I will be starting where I need to create an application that pulls data from a mongoDB database and then uses the graphing functionality in matlab.

Basically I would like to use the native mongoDB query functionality to be able to get small amounts of data and then pass that over to matlab to graph. Ideally I could do this with a GUI that would be able to ask which collection to pull from, etc and then automatically passes the data over to matlab when asked. I already have a matlab app that graphs what I need I would just need to pass it inputs.

I'm new to programming entirely, so I was pointed in the direction to use React to create a standalone local app in javascript (which also works with mongoDB). I've run into a problem where it seems like I cannot call matlab from javascript, so I would have to use a bridge language or something.

Does anyone have a better starting point for this? Completely open to switching languages if that's the better call here. Or maybe I have it backwards and should be writing scripts in C++ that matlab can call? Just not sure where to start...

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/mps/restfuljson/example-web-based-bond-pricing-tool-using-javascript.html or https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Answer (score -1):

You can try Python Flask, this is the best option in my opinion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31305096)